# Accidentally overwritten a latex file and would like to retrieve older version?

Tags: pdftex, texmaker

Today accidentally I cancelled the whole body of my report and then compiled. I did not have a backup or anything and the pdf and the code are overwitten with a blank report. I tried to find the files with apps such as recuva but it did not work. Do you have any suggestion? thanks (I was working with texmaker + miktex)

Comment: Welcome to  TeX SX! What are your distribution and your editor?

Comment: texMaker with miktex

Comment: CTL+Z should work if your editor is still open.

Comment: Doesn't TeXmaker make a backup file whenever there's a modification?

Comment: Ctrl+Z did not work I do not know why! Regarding the backup file honestly I do not know if one is created after a modification...I hope so but I would not know where to find it. Any suggestions?

Comment: "something like recuva" will most likely be your only bet at this point.  And the sooner you recover them, the better.  If you'd like, you can open a chat room, and I can guide you through the process of how to check if anything is left.  Overwriting a file is usually pretty serious, because it doesn't go to the recycle bin -- it gets new data written over it.